# touch isn't detecting on libgdx button

Tags: java, button, touch, libgdx, actor

I'm new to libgdx and learning libgdx scene2d.

In menu screen constructor I had created a stage with the device's resolution
and added stage to input processor:

```
stage = new Stage(800, 480, false);
stage.getCamera().position.set(400, 240, 0);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Now, I created a button and added it to stage:

```
PButton start = new PButton(Assets.btn, Assets.btn_p, Assets.font50,
            "START");
start.setPosition(600, 400);
start.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
        super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        getGame().setScreen(new GameScreen1(getGame()));
        System.out.println("set game");
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(start);
```

where `PButton` extends the `Button` class as:

```
public class PButton extends Button {
    private BitmapFont font;
    private String text;
    private float sizex;
    private float sizey;
    private float posx;
    private float posy;

    public PButton(TextureRegion up, TextureRegion down, BitmapFont font,
        String text) {
        super(new TextureRegionDrawable(up), new TextureRegionDrawable(down));
        this.font = font;
        this.text = text;
        this.sizex = up.getRegionWidth();
        this.sizey = down.getRegionHeight();
        setSize(sizex, sizey);
        font.setScale(Initiate.getM_ratio());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
            font.draw(batch, text, posx + sizex / 2 - font.getBounds(text).width
            / 2, posy + sizey / 2 + font.getBounds(text).height / 2);

    }

    @Override
    public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
            this.posx = x;
            this.posy = y;
            super.setPosition(posx, posy);
    }
}
```

but when I click on the button, it doesn't get input.

UPDATE: problem solved after a deep debugging I found that my stage.dispose() method of previous screen if not called properly
anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not act to `Gesture` on a Button. It's a click or a touch but not a gesture. Change this to a `ClickListener`and the onClick action and it should work.
Regards

Comment: thanx for your suggestion
but this didn't helped me
still touch isn't detecting